# How to build a home screen using gridview in react native?

Tags: react-native, gridview, touchableopacity

I need to build a home screen with grid view in react-native. And that grid view should contain four Image buttons. Each image button should redirect to different pages. I am using the react-native-super-grid package.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only 4 image button than no need to make a complex grid .  Use below code only and if you need a complex gird than use this YouTube video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm2FcQOmLGo&t=53s) for better understanding.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View,Image } from 'react-native';

export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
      <View style={{flex: 1, }}>
         <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', }}>
        <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{flex:1}} />
        <Image source={{uri: 'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/512/1*qUlxDdY3T-rDtJ4LhLGkEg.png'}}
       style={{flex:1}} />

      </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', }}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://rawgit.com/gorangajic/react-icons/master/react-icons.svg'}}
       style={{flex:1}} />

        <Image  source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{flex:1}} />

      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlexDirectionBasics);
```

**Let me know if need more discussion**

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Im using Touchable opacity. When user clicks the button it should redirect to different pages.

Comment: Hi anil,
I'm using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-super-grid.
instead of text, I need button for button i used touchable opacity.

Comment: but why button only. i think touchable opacity is better than button

Comment: I'm using touchable opacity only. But my problem is, in render has 4 items and in renderitems i added four buttons when i run the app it shows 12. renderitems occurring twice

Comment: Hello Anil,
check the code I added above
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035858/7818289

Answer (score 0):

You can install "npm install react-native-super-grid" and try this. You can change itemDimension then it will change number of icons should display on screen. This is only sample you can change what ever you needs.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  PixelRatio,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Content } from "native-base";
import GridView from "react-native-super-grid";

const buttons = [
  {
name: "test1",
image: require("./src/icons/test1.png"),
key: 1
  },
  {
name: "test2",
image: require("./src/icons/test2.png"),
key: 2
  },
  {
name: "test3",
image: require("./src/icons/test3.png"),
key: 3
  },
  {
name: "test4",
image: require("./src/icons/test4.png"),
key: 4
  },
];

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onPress(){
  
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Content contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}>
          <GridView
            itemDimension={180}
            items={buttons}
            renderItem={item => (
              <View style={styles.gridCompenentContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
                  activeOpacity={0.8}
                  style={styles.touchView}
                >
                  <Image
                    style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
                    source={item.image}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.textView}>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}                     </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  contentContainerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  gridCompenentContainer: {
    width: 160,
    height: 140,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  touchView: {
    width: 80,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#0099cc"
  },
  textView: {
    width: 140,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    width: 140,
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#0099cc"
  }
});

export default Home;
```

Comment: Naveen,
When i run your code using snack.expo it shows error as "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.onPressButton.bind')"

Comment: sorry it should be change onPress.bind(this) not as onPressButton.bind(this)

Comment: You should add image path as it you used

Comment: it is not navigating

Comment: What do you want to do? please give brief explanation in here. I'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code according to user package.

**RenderItem function is work such as loop.**

**when you put 4 objects in sections array  RenderItem will make a loop for 4 time.**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Image style={styles.img} source={require('./assets/3.jpg')} />
                <SuperGridSectionList
                    itemDimension={130}

                    sections={[
                        {
                            // all your style and data will be here according to your grid package
                            data: [

                                { name: '1' }, { name: '2' },
                                { name: '3' }, { name: '4' },

                            ]
                        }
                    ]}

                    style={styles.gridView}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => { alert("clicked me") }}>
                                <Image source={require("./assets/set2.png")} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>
```

Comment: Thanks anil,
But i need to four images for the button(1,2,3,4). so, that it will redirect to respective pages.

Comment: than use images url like this 
 data: [

                                { name: '1',url:'www.imag.com/abc.jph' }, { name: '2' },
                                { name: '3' }, { name: '4' },

                            ]

thats it

Comment: Thanks. How to push each item from section data? so that if user press 1 or 2 it redirects to respective pages.
But now all of pages are redirecting to the same page.

Comment: you have dynamic data  or static data

Comment: static data as  static navigationOptions = {
    title : 'MainHome',
  };

Comment: Plz check this I edited my answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035858/7818289.
How onPress will work dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

#### thara### please refer this to get know how to implement react navigation or official documentation [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html).

You can add route for button press event. like

```js
        
        
        onPress={() =>
          this.props.navigation.navigate('screen2');
        }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation#react-navigation

Comment: let me give some time I'll forward you.

Comment: that works. what is the problem you faced? If you have issue please mention it here or I'll forward you sample project for you.